# calling an ajax function via html

Tags: html, ajax

i have an ajax function(with arguments) and i want to call it via html

the calling now is:

```
<a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='$wordNum'></a>
```

and the ajax function starts with:

```
$("a.vote_down").click(function(args){
```

how do i add the arguments to the html code

Comment: What arguments do you want to pass? Can you show more complete code?

Comment: i want to pass two strings from html

Comment: Can you please post this HTML?

Comment: function fixMenu($wordNum,$form){
return "

<span class='vote_buttons' id='vote_buttons$wordNum'>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_up' id='$wordNum'></a>
  <a href='javascript:;' class='vote_down' id='$wordNum'></a>
 </span>
 
; 
}
we want to send $wordNum and $form

Comment: I think your `fixMenu` function is wrong. You want to have the **value** of `$wordNum` as ID right? Then you have to use string concatenation like: `'<span class="vote_buttons" id="vote_buttons' + $wordNum + '">'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the way you do that is to get the value of an HTML element in your click handler:

```
$("a.vote_down").click(function(){
    var arg1 = $("#argument1").val(); // Gets the argument from the value of an element
    var art2 = $("#argument2").text(); // Gets the argument from the text of an element

    // Do some fancy stuff
});
```

Comment: my question is how do i send the args from the html call

Comment: @nisnis84: Just add `callAjaxFunction(arg1, arg2)` to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:functionName(arg1, arg2);">
```

Point of note: it's always a good idea to also provide an alternative for those with JavaScript disabled. For example, in your `href` attribute you could link to a page that has a normal HTML form to submit the vote.